# What percentage of the speed of light would an object achieve the Planck energy?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, mass-energy, physical-constants

As energy is proportional to the speed of light at what percentage of the speed of light would an object's energy reach the Planck energy level?

Comment: *energy is proportional to the speed of light* No, it isn’t.

Comment: This question is not very well phrased.  Anyways... have you tried calculating this yourself and if so where's the conceptual problem?

Comment: The answer depends on the mass of the object, which you didn’t specify.

Comment: It is unclear whether by “energy” you are including the object’s rest energy.

Answer (score 1):

For a general case of arbitrary rest mass body solve equation for $v$ :

$$ m_oc^{2}\left({\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-{\frac {v^{2}}{c^{2}}}}}}-1 \right) = m_pc^2$$

Where $m_o$ is body rest mass and $m_p$ is Plank mass.
It  comes from fact that in your situation relativistic kinetic energy should be equals to Plank energy, namely $E_k = E_p$.

Comment: Thank you for responding. However that can't be correct as moving at the speed of would mean infinite energy. However although the Planck energy is large it isn't infinite only being

Ep = 1.96 × 10^⁹J

That's not infinite energy.

Comment: If you solve for $v$ as I recommended, then you would see that it is $v < c$, and thus relativistic kinetic energy to which Plank energy is comparable is not infinite. No discrepancies here at all.

Comment: But what happens if the velocity does equal C, shouldnt that energy goto infinity? Thus wouldn't that be more energy on top of the Planck energy?  If so how does that make any sense as we believe there should be no greater energy we should theoretically be to reach other than the Planck energy? The Planck energy is massive but it's still a far cry from infinity.

Comment: *we believe there should be no greater energy we should theoretically be to reach other than the Planck energy* That’s not true. The Planck energy is a lot of energy for an elementary particle, but only a modest amount of energy for a macroscopic object. For example, your car’s gas tank holds chemical energy on the order of the Planck energy.